# How can I fix importlib on python3.10 so that it can call entry_points() properly?

Tags: python, typeerror, entry-point, python-importlib

I am using *Python 3.10* on *Ubuntu 22.04* working on a project that uses [*Farama Foundation*'s *gymnasium* library](https://pypi.org/project/gymnasium/). When *gymnasium* is imported, it uses *importlib* to get *entry points*, but when I ran `import gymnasium` into *IDLE* I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gymnasium/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gymnasium.envs.registration import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gymnasium/envs/__init__.py", line 382, in <module>
    load_plugin_envs()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gymnasium/envs/registration.py", line 565, in load_plugin_envs
    for plugin in metadata.entry_points(group=entry_point):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1009, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 459, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1006, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 941, in _normalized_name
    return self._name_from_stem(stem) or super()._normalized_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 622, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 871, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I asked one of the creators of *gymnasium* about this issue on *GitHub*, and they asked me to print out a list of entry points, so I ran the following:

```py
from importlib.metadata import *
eps = entry_points()
```

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1009, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 459, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1006, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 941, in _normalized_name
    return self._name_from_stem(stem) or super()._normalized_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 622, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 871, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What this seems to suggest is that one of the names that `entry_points()` is searching for is not in the correct format. I am unsure of how to fix this. I am willing to uninstall *Python 3.10* completely and reinstall it and all additional packages from scratch, but I would prefer an approach that is less aggressive.

Comment: Needs debugging. Maybe we can narrow it down to a specific distribution. You could iterate over all distributions and print their entry points. Maybe something like `for d in importlib.metadata.distributions(): print(d); for e in d.entry_points: print(e)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import importlib_metadata as md
>>> dists = md.distributions()
>>> broken = [dist for dist in dists if dist.name is None]
>>> for dist in broken:
...     print(dist._path)
```

It will list the paths of distributions that are the problem. Reinstalling or deleting them will stop the error.

[This guy had the same problem](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/774#issuecomment-886657451)